Simple Queries - Sent
I'm new to writing queries but I thought this SENT query would be simple. I'm just trying to get All sends for the last 30 days. But when I run the query, nothing populates in the DE and nothing populates in the Action Log.
I feel like I'm SO close but as I've been building out my automation I keep running into Super niche errors. Do I need a primary key?
Here's my query:
SELECT
    AccountID, 
    OYBAccountID,
    JobID,
    ListID,
    BatchID,
    SubscriberID,
    SubscriberKey,
    EventDate,
    Domain,
    TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
    TriggeredSendCustomerKey
FROM _Sent
WHERE Eventdate > Dateadd(day, -30, Getdate())  

Here are my DE values:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The sent query looks fine. Are you running it inside a business unit that is sending out emails? A primary key is not needed for your data extension. Alternatively, if you access to Query Studio, which is available on the appexchange, you can run your query to see the results in a temporary data extension.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I'd recommend first of all some adjustments to your data extension fields. Depending on how you execute email sends in your account, email studio sends won't have Triggered Send values. So both both triggered send object id and customer key columns should be nullable.
